# math.random image re-appearing off screen

Tags: android, lua, coronasdk

Having a small issue with a collision and a math.random sending my images off the screen.

So what I have is a ball hits a brick and the brick will randomly re-locate, but the brick image keeps going off screen. The brick is also rotated 90 degrees so I'm not sure if it effects anything. There is also a 61px tall image at the top of the screen that the image keeps re-locating behind and I was thinking a - 61 added to it would help, but I haven't had any luck.

```
xRandom = math.random(display.contentWidth - brick.width)
yRandom = math.random(display.contentHeight - brick.height)
transition.to(brick, {delay = 200, x = xRandom, y= yRandom , time=0})
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have it, the `xRandom` will be between 1 and `display.contentWidth - brick.width`: if the anchor point of the brick is its x=0, then this ensures that the brick can't be positioned too far right. Perhaps the x anchor is not at 0, or anchor is x=0 but this does not correspond to left side of image (perhaps the way it was loaded? can't tell without seeing code).

Same goes for y coordinate: is 0 at top of screen and increases downward. So `yRandom` will be between 1 and `display.contentHeight - brick.height` which will ensure the brick is visible if its y anchor is at y=0 and that this anchor is the top of the image.

If you have an image that is at top of screen, you should limit the smallest y to be larger than that image's height, ie use `yRandom = math.random(topImageHeight, display.contentHeight - brick.height)`.

It is impossible to tell if part of the problem is due to rotation without seeing your code. If you can post a minimal example that I can run then it will make it a lot easier to provide a more accurate answer.